# Subtracting Running Total until 0

Tags: sql, oracle, case, cumulative-sum

I am trying to get a running total of subtraction to work for my `avail_relief_amt` column.  The goal is to make `(qty_filled / qty_total)` as close to 100% as possible, which is what the `room_to_improve` column is for.

Current Query:

```
    SELECT
    t2_date,
    part_no,
    issue_group,
    level,
    p_category,
    qty_filled,
    qty_total,
    relief_amt,
    curr_mth_note,
    carryover_note,
    room_to_improve,
    avail_relief_amt,
    CASE
        WHEN avail_relief_amt != 0 THEN ( qty_total - room_to_improve )
        ELSE NULL
    END AS new_qty_total
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            t2_date,
            part_no,
            issue_group,
            level,
            p_category,
            qty_filled,
            qty_total,
            relief_amt,
            curr_mth_note,
            carryover_note,
            CASE
                WHEN qty_filled < qty_total THEN ( qty_total - qty_filled )
                ELSE NULL
            END AS room_to_improve,
            avail_relief_amt
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    t2_date,
                    part_no,
                    issue_group,
                    level,
                    p_category,
                    qty_filled,
                    qty_total,
                    relief_amt,
                    curr_mth_note,
                    carryover_note,
                    CASE
                        WHEN curr_mth_note IS NOT NULL THEN relief_amt
                        ELSE NULL
                    END AS avail_relief_amt
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            t1.t2_date,
                            t1.part_no,
                            t1.issue_group,
                            t1.level,
                            t1.p_category,
                            t1.qty_filled,
                            t1.qty_total,
                            mv.relief_amt,
                            mv.curr_mth_note,
                            mv.carryover_note
                        FROM
                            table_detail_mv mv,
                            table_part_con t1
                        WHERE
                            t1.part_no = mv.part_no
                            AND t1.t2_date = mv.t2_date
                        GROUP BY
                            t1.t2_date,
                            t1.issue_group,
                            t1.level,
                            t1.part_no,
                            t1.p_category,
                            t1.qty_filled,
                            t1.qty_total,
                            mv.relief_amt,
                            mv.curr_mth_note,
                            mv.carryover_note
                        ORDER BY
                            t1.t2_date,
                            t1.issue_group,
                            t1.level DESC
                    )
            )
    )
ORDER BY
    t2_date,
    part_no,
    issue_group,
    level DESC
```

Current Output:

[image]

The `avail_relief_amt` column starts out with whatever number is within the `relief_amt` column.  If `avail_relief_amt > room_to_improve` the next `avail_relief_amt` should be whatever is left from `(avail_relief_amt - room_to_improve)`.  In my above output, since there is no `room_to_improve` for row-2, so it needs to go down to the next row, etc., until `avail_relief_amt = 0`.

Desired Output:

[image]

***Edit***

I've removed the `room_to_improve`, `avail_relief_amt`, and `new_qty_total` columns from my above query, as they were just added in thoughts of helping visualize my end goal.

Current output (without above columns):

[image]

Better explanation of end goal:

- Getting `qty_total` / `qty_filled` as close to 100% as possible, by taking from the `relief_amt` until it equals 0.
- The `relief_amt` will go down the line of priority (ignoring the 'Late's). 
  Order of priority is (`issue_group='1', s_level='80'`) - (`issue_group='1', s_level='100'`) - (`issue_group='2/3 ', s_level='80'`) - (`issue_group='2/3 ', s_level='100'`)
- With the above output, there is 27 needed in order to make `qty_total = qty_filled`, so that number is taken away from the `relief_amt` (of 57). Leaving `relief_amt=30`.
- Then the query jumps down to the next priority, but since 94 = 94, there is no `relief_amt` needed to be used, so it goes down to the next row (remembering to skip the 'Late').
- Now we are to needing to get `qty_total=226`, closer to `qty_filled=125`, but we only have a `relief_amt=30`. So the remaining `relief_amt` gets taken from that `qty_total=226`, making that new `qty_total=196`, and then we are out of `relief_amt`.

It's super confusing I know, and has me and my coworkers pretty stumped because of all the variables and recurring equations that are going on.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Is there any column that shows the order the rows should be read in?

Comment: @Error_2646 yes... sorry I tried to edit my code for confidentiality purposes and forgot to include those back in. They will be partitioned by date, part, issue_group, p_category, and level.  The `qty_total` column is grouping by level

Comment: @KassieB It would help if you gave as a sample of your data in order to optimize your queries.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution  but since you didn't have the original data, my solution used your query as a view.

So, you must create a view with the syntax:

```
create view currentOutput as select ...your current query here... ;
```

Additionally, you need a date field which I assumed would be named something like `dateEntry`.

And then you can do the following:

```
 SELECT dateEntry,
       room_to_improve,
       CASE
           WHEN temp.AVAIL_RELIEF_AMT - NVL(SUMPREVIOUSROOMTOIMPROVE, 0) < 0 THEN 0
           ELSE temp.AVAIL_RELIEF_AMT - NVL(SUMPREVIOUSROOMTOIMPROVE, 0)
       END AS AVAIL_RELEIF_AMT,
       new_qty_total
FROM
  ( SELECT c1.*,

     (SELECT sum(room_to_improve)
      FROM currentOutput
      WHERE dateEntry < c1.dateEntry) AS sumPreviousRoomToImprove
   FROM currentOutput c1
   ORDER BY dateEntry )TEMP ;
```

Result:

> ```
> DATEENTRY -ROOM_TO_IMPROVE-   AVAIL_RELEIF_AMT-   NEW_QTY_TOTAL-
> 1-    27  -57-    67
> 2-        -30-    
> 3-    101-    -30-    125
> 4-    49- 0-  177-
> ```

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2c074fe2adc232fd596d623e1cee8123

Comment: I've updated the query to show the entire thing I have so far.

Comment: @KassieB Have a try at the current solution and tell me if it's the results you want. I will try to re-visit this. The trick I basically did was to take all the entries from before the current entry, and do a sum. Then you subtract this sum from the current. If the result is negative, you convert to zero.

Comment: I have been trying to get it to work, but it's such a tricky calculation that I (and the coworkers I've asked to help with also so far) are struggling.  I'm going to edit my post and add a better vision of the data, along with a better explanation of what I am trying to do overall, and maybe that may help shed some light.  I technically don't need the `room_to_improve`, `avail_relief_amt`, and `new_qty_total` columns ... just thought they would help visualize my end goal.

Comment: @KassieB Another option would be to include them as columns and use an update statement to calculate them. But in general getting the SUM of all the previous room_to_improve might be a way to go.

Comment: I just added an Edit section to my initial question that helps further breakdown my end goal.  Since those 3 columns were just calculations I was doing in order to try to display my end goal, they can be removed/manipulated to be whatever calculations I'm needing for all of this to work.

Comment: @KassieB it helps to have sample data (create statements, insert statements).

Comment: All the data is being pulled from other views/tables off the server, so I'm technically not inputting or creating anything, aside from the query to eventually be able to create a report off of it.

Comment: was finally able to get around to your solution, and it provided me the same output as what I already had.  Nothing happened to the avail_relief_amt column at all

Comment: @KassieB , please see my example : 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2c074fe2adc232fd596d623e1cee8123 . 

The avail column should change. 

But this will only work ( like in my example) under one condition. 
You must create a view that shows the sample data you gave us. `create view currentOutput as [put query here that was producing Current Output:]`